# Query to assign serial numbers for rows without changing the order of rows

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-order-by, lag

I have a SQL table that consists of the Driver Truck trips which carries containers. Each time a trip is made, the records/rows are stored. If he carries 1 container in a trip, then I've stored "1 Unit" under Unitcount Field. If he carries 2 Containers, then 2 Rows are created with the Unitcount Field value as  "2 Units".

Actually I am calculating the driver trip cost for a specific week for all the drivers. Below picture explains what Data I have and the result I need (Column highlited in green).  Here i want the query to fill the "Result" field based on the No. of trips a driver performed in that day. It must reset the value of the "Result" column whenever the driver name is changed or Date is changed. That is, if the driver has carried 2 units, then "Result" value must treat those 2 rows as a single trip (means trip count value should not increment).

Please note, the order of the rows shouldn't be changed.

I have tried to explain my requirement precisely as I can. Please do comment in case you need additional information.

[image]

Use the below scripts for creating the table and inserting the data (for workaround) Column "Tid" is the primary key.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Test_Table](
[Tid] [bigint] NOT NULL,
[DriverName] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[Cardgdate] [date] NULL,
[Dircid] [int] NULL,
[Load] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
[UnitCount] [nchar](10) NULL,
[Result] [int] NULL,
CONSTRAINT [PK_Test_Table] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [Tid] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253293, N'Naveed Khan', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 34, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253320, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253358, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253407, N'Naveed Khan', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253434, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253449, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253492, N'Naveed Khan', '20200823 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253516, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 34, N'Agent', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253520, N'Naveed Khan', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 34, N'Agent', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253525, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 34, N'Agent', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253576, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253592, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (253599, N'Naveed Khan', '20200824 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254647, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254659, N'Naveed Khan', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254664, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254711, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254743, N'Chandra Shekar', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254744, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254745, N'Naveed Khan', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254783, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254785, N'Chandra Shekar', '20200825 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254802, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 39, N'Terminal', N'2 Units   ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254803, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 39, N'Terminal', N'2 Units   ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254815, N'Chandra Shekar', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 34, N'Agent', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254833, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254900, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 39, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254904, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 39, N'Terminal', N'2 Units   ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254905, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 39, N'Terminal', N'2 Units   ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254927, N'Chandra Shekar', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254964, N'Aas Muhammad', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254986, N'Danish Imtiaz', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254987, N'Naveed Khan', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
INSERT INTO [dbo].[Test_Table]([Tid], [DriverName], [Cardgdate], [Dircid], [Load], [UnitCount], [Result]) VALUES (254992, N'Chandra Shekar', '20200826 00:00:00.000', 30, N'Terminal', N'1 Unit    ', 0)
```

NOTE: Yesterday I posted my query in a different way (link is below) and I got few suggestions as well. The problem I faced was, yesterday I had queried for only 1 driver and for 1 date. But when I tried their suggested answers for multiple drivers for a weekly period, the "result" column was filled with continuous values from the begin of the day till end. However, here I want to reset the value of the "Result" column whenever the driver name is changed, Date is changed.

[Query to assign serial number for rows without grouping together and without changing the order of rows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63999745/sql-server-query-to-assign-serial-number-for-rows-without-grouping-together-and)

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Why do the first two rows of data are considered different trips, while they relate to the same driver, date and unit count?

Comment: Hi GMB, Thank you for your valuable comment. Actually I am gonna pay the incentives for these drivers based on no. of trips they handled each day... That is, $20 for First Trip, $20 for Second Trip, $25 for Third Trip and $30 for the Fourth Trip. This is the reason i cannot group them together. It was very easy for me if all drivers carries "1 Unit" at a time. The situation became worse for me when some drivers carries "2 Units" in a single trip. Infact the columns above is an extract from our production table which consists of 70+ Columns...

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I found this script and works fine till the row having "2 Units". That is Driver Naveed Khan has carried 4 actual trips on 26/08/2020. But as per this query, it says he performed 6 trips. Small tuning may help me solve my query.

```
    SELECT tid,  
    drivername,cardgdate,
   dircid, load,
   Unitcount,
   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY drivername,cardgdate ORDER BY tid) AS Result
FROM   TEST_TABLE
```

And below is the output i got from the above query:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Fine one thing i understood is that displaying the "Tid" Column would not help in getting my desired result.
So I am redefining my output as below pic. That is remove the Tid column, merge the rows having "2 Units" as one row.
Hope this may give me some chances.

[image]

Eventhough i removed the Tid column, the order should not be changed.